# Converting the format of a WSDL file (Java?)

Tags: java, wsdl, transform

I work with a system (Salesforce) that can only consume document/literal wrapped WSDL files.  However, my customers need me to connect with older systems that generate other formats of WSDL file (RPC literal for example or just doc literal).  So I often receive wsdl files in 'unfriendly' formats and I have a Hell Of A time trying to shoehorn it into a format acceptable by Salesforce.  Basically, there can be no external references in the wsdl and it must be doc/literal wrapped.

So... I was thinking that a sneaky way to solve this issue might be to consume the wsdl in Java (jax.ws) and then recreate the wsdl from Java programmatically with a single call.

Has this problem been solved before?  If not, then am I on the right track?  Has anyone solved this wsdl transformation issue before?   I assume XSLT could probably do the job for a smarter man than myself, but I've got to work with the brain I was issued and it seems determined to learn the minimum possible about wsdls in order to solve this problem.

TLDR: can I consume/create arbitrary format WSDLs with java so I can create WSDLs in wrapped doc/literal format with no attributes (elements instead) and no imports (a completely self contained WSDL should be the output).

If you can help me solve this problem I will buy you a pizza!  That's right.  I'll email you a papaJohn/Dominos/Pizzahut coupon (or even call your local pizza joint and buy it for you if you want to give me your home address/phone number - which you probably don't).

Comment: Why do you think that the same on-the-wire format can be equivalently represented as doc/lit and rpc/lit?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question.  My assumption is that SOAP is SOAP is SOAP but that there are multiple ways to define an acceptable communication protocol for any given app.  I assumed those multiple ways are the different wsdl formats and that I should be able to convert between one and another.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I read your comment again, more slowly!  Are you saying that they can't?  you're right.  I had presumed that they could.  Am I wrong?

Comment: My gut instinct is that there there is not necessarily an equivalent doc/literal WSDL that describes the same wire protocol as any arbitrary rpc/literal. But I don't feel confident, and I wondered what you knew about it.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about RPC.  But I do know that many attribute based, externalFile-referencing wsdls can be converted into self-contained wrapped doc-literal as we've been forced into doing it by hand on a number of occasions.  I was hoping to become a hero by automating this process.  I was surprised there wasn't any auto-converter online and thought that the JAX.ws package might be my friend in this endeavor.

Comment: Sounds like you could write an adaptor webapp to sit between sales force and your third party service. The webapp would accept calls in a doc wrapped format / wsdl of your creation and then call out in the third party format. But maybe this is what you're doing already?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest an approach, but you may or may not find it helpful.

Apache CXF includes a great deal of code for building a model of a service based on a WSDL and then on the other hand building a WSDL based on the model. You might get somewhere by starting with that code and trying to write more code to map the model so that you get the wsdl you want.

I'm tolerable confident that nothing built-in-to JAX-WS is going to help you here, but I surely don't have it memorized. You might also find a deeper pool of relevant expertise at the CXF user mailing list.